# Combining codeigniter active records function with regular sql statement

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Is it possible to use codeigniter active records functions as an add on to the end of a regular sql statement? Something like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = 'red'";
$this->db->WHERE_IN('code', $array);
$query = $this->db->get($sql);
return $query->result();
```

I really need the where_in function so i can apply an array of values, in which the number of values is constantly changing

Why do I want to do it this way instead of just doing it all in active records function? Because when I used just active records functions, I kept getting errors, and I don't want to spend more time smashing my head against the table in frustration.

Comment: Nope, as far as i know its not possible. `implode()` your array in a string and use a regular query.

Comment: You might be best to ask why you're getting the errors, as AR can be very useful to run your queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$imploded_array  = implode(",", $array);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = 'red' AND code IN ({$imploded_array})";
//$this->db->WHERE_IN('code', $array);
$query = $this->db->get($sql);
return $query->result();
```

Comment: That worked, except when it hits ({$imploded_array}) its giving me (value,value), I need it to be ('value','value') or else i just get errors